# Creating a Javascript Variable with "+variableName+" In It?

Tags: javascript

I can get the variable I created to work but not with the variable `"+number+"` in it

**This is what I have so far:**

```
//this works when i remove "+number+"
var test = "text row 1 \n\n text row 2 \n\n number "+number+" text row3"


$(document).mousemove(function(event){
var result = confirm(test);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
alert(test);
});
```

how do I get this to work?

**Update:**

`number` is defined in an external script that is included into the page.  It's not my javascript so I don't know how it's defined, I just need a way make the variable work with `number` in it

Comment: where is `number` declared/defined?

Comment: Incomplete source code... Can you edit your question and how where you declare the `number` variable. If the return is `undefined` or `Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined` in the browser console then it's because you haven't declared it.

Comment: Please check the error console in your web browser for errors

Comment: Your code lacks... code. Also, don't use `alert()` to debug. Instead, use console.log(). Opening the console will show you the warning, errors and the print you want.

Comment: @DanielA.White `number` is defined in a external script so im not sure how to include it i just know the variable

Comment: Please learn to write a good question, "doesn't work" isn't a reasonable description. Please identify what you expect as the output and what you actually get. Also, you **must** include how *number* is created, e.g. declared as a global? Local? Implicit global? Is the script that declares it already loaded? Yet to load? See [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

the variable number is not defined in the given code. It has to be defined first.

```
 var number = 0; // for example
```

if number is defined somewhere else (that you cannot make sure about it), then here is a suggestion

```
 number = (typeof(number)=='undefined')? 0 : number ;
 var test = "text row 1 \n\n text row 2 \n\n number "+number+" text row3"
```

The previous code would evaluate (examine) first the value of number, if it is not defined before, it will assign the value 0 for it, otherwise will return the value of number as required.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: its defined in an external script

Comment: You can remove the brackets: `number = typeof number == 'undefined'? 0 : number`. ;-)

Comment: correct for the machine. But parentheses make it more readable for humans, I prefer to use it.